# Is there a name for the repetitious use of the word "of"?

Tags: repetition, prepositions

In the Bible, one can read about "the tree *of* knowledge *of* good and evil," which was situated in the "garden *of* Eden." 
This seems to me as though it may be an artefact of translation from Hebrew, possibly on account of the fact that English doesn't have a specific genetive case. Is there some particular name for this phenomenon, or is it just that the word happens to be more common than average sometimes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two considerations here.  The first is that *of* is a versatile word that conveys various relationships, many more than just simply one of possession.  The *OED* lists 63 different senses (many of them obsolete; sorry, but I didn't count).  I can say possessively "a book **of** mine", meaning "my book", but to be cured **of** a disease and to be in fear **of** one's life are different.

The second problem is that biblical Hebrew doesn't have either a genitive case or a handy word like *of*.  Hebrew relies on a chain of juxtaposed  words.  Thus what we translate as "the Garden of Eden" is *gan eyden*, which in Hebrew looks more like Marven Gardens (or Marvin Gardens if you're playing Monopoly).  Except, of course, for the plural in English.

Likewise "the tree of knowledge of good and evil" is

> *etz* (tree) *hadaas* (the knowledge) *tov* (good) *v'ra* (and evil)

To complicate things further, there apparently is a Hebrew idiomatic form of a word and its opposite (e.g., "good and evil), which figuratively means everything.  Go [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3141392?seq=11#page_scan_tab_contents) for details.  So what we have in Hebrew is

> The knowledge tree, good and evil

which is to say the "universal knowledge tree" (except that in English the article belongs to *tree*, and in Hebrew it belongs to *knowledge*).

tl;dr English and Hebrew grammars are much different, and translators rely on the flexibility of an English preposition to capture the meaning.

The transliteration is mine, and I hereby apologize for its shortcomings.  As a transliteration, I've written it left to right.  Remember that in Hebrew is would be read in the proper direction.  An explanation of the Hebrew genitive construction may be found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=p3FIoT0s3yYC&pg=PT151&lpg=PT151&dq=biblical%20hebrew%20genitive%20case&source=bl&ots=dYM3Akfacn&sig=QSW50k1L4ntfQC9lzPYm3Al_SxM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHsan5yeLJAhWMPT4KHWxBCIQ4ChDoAQgpMAQ#v=onepage&q=biblical%20hebrew%20genitive%20case&f=false).  And those who wish to follow along in Genesis may go [here](http://www.scripture4all.org/OnlineInterlinear/OTpdf/gen2.pdf).